# Propagating entered TextTab value throughout PDF using DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

We are using DocuSign's .NET Client to send out contracts to customers. One of the signer's is responsible for entering a contract number. This number occurs multiple times in the contract and ideally we'd like it to be automatically propagated to each of the fields that have the same name, however if this is not possible the signer could enter it manually in each location.

I have tried adding the TextTab once, and tried adding it multiple times. I've also tried prefixing the label with \* and in every case there is only one TextTab displayed and the value is never propagated.

I'm including the rest trace for our request so that someone can hopefully identify what I need to change so the values appear multiple times or that the TextTab appears multiple times.

```
POST: https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/111111/envelopes?api_password=true

Headers:
X-DocuSign-Authentication:<DocuSignCredentials><Username>****</Username><Password>****</Password><IntegratorKey>****</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
Host:demo.docusign.net
Content-Length:1217301
Expect:100-continue
Connection:Keep-Alive

Request Stream:

--00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data

{
    "emailSubject": "Anfrage 2015-06-25T09:10:49: Signieren Sie jetzt Ihren Acme Vertrag",
    "status": "sent",
    "compositeTemplates": [
        {
            "compositeTemplateId": "1",
            "inlineTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": "1",
                    "recipients": {
                        "signers": [
                            {
                                "email": "mjones@foo.com",
                                "name": "Max Jones",
                                "recipientId": "1",
                                "routingOrder": "1",
                                "tabs": {
                                    "signHereTabs": [
                                        {
                                            "documentId": 1,
                                            "tabLabel": "Signature_LesseeContract1_eSignSignHere",
                                            "recipientId": "1"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "documentId": 1,
                                            "tabLabel": "Signature_LesseeSepa1_eSignSignHere",
                                            "recipientId": "1"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "documentId": 1,
                                            "tabLabel": "Signature_LesseeBillAndCollect1_eSignSignHere",
                                            "recipientId": "1"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "documentId": 1,
                                            "tabLabel": "Signature_LesseeRequest1_eSignSignHere",
                                            "recipientId": "1"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "documentId": 1,
                                            "tabLabel": "Signature_LesseeBillAndCollectSepa1_eSignSignHere",
                                            "recipientId": "1"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "fullNameTabs": [
                                        {
                                            "documentId": 1,
                                            "tabLabel": "Signature_LesseeContract1_eSignFullName",
                                            "recipientId": "1"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "documentId": 1,
                                            "tabLabel": "Signature_LesseeSepa1_eSignFullName",
                                            "recipientId": "1"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "documentId": 1,
                                            "tabLabel": "Signature_LesseeBillAndCollect1_eSignFullName",
                                            "recipientId": "1"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "documentId": 1,
                                            "tabLabel": "Signature_LesseeRequest1_eSignFullName",
                                            "recipientId": "1"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "documentId": 1,
                                            "tabLabel": "Signature_LesseeBillAndCollectSepa1_eSignFullName",
                                            "recipientId": "1"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "textTabs": [
                                        {
                                            "shared": false,
                                            "requireInitialOnSharedChange": false,
                                            "requireAll": false,
                                            "locked": false,
                                            "concealValueOnDocument": false,
                                            "disableAutoSize": false,
                                            "templateLocked": false,
                                            "templateRequired": false,
                                            "documentId": 1,
                                            "tabLabel": "Signature_ContractNumber",
                                            "required": true,
                                            "recipientId": "1"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "shared": false,
                                            "requireInitialOnSharedChange": false,
                                            "requireAll": false,
                                            "locked": false,
                                            "concealValueOnDocument": false,
                                            "disableAutoSize": false,
                                            "templateLocked": false,
                                            "templateRequired": false,
                                            "documentId": 1,
                                            "tabLabel": "Signature_ContractNumber",
                                            "required": true,
                                            "recipientId": "1"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "shared": false,
                                            "requireInitialOnSharedChange": false,
                                            "requireAll": false,
                                            "locked": false,
                                            "concealValueOnDocument": false,
                                            "disableAutoSize": false,
                                            "templateLocked": false,
                                            "templateRequired": false,
                                            "documentId": 1,
                                            "tabLabel": "Signature_ContractNumber",
                                            "required": true,
                                            "recipientId": "1"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "shared": false,
                                            "requireInitialOnSharedChange": false,
                                            "requireAll": false,
                                            "locked": false,
                                            "concealValueOnDocument": false,
                                            "disableAutoSize": false,
                                            "templateLocked": false,
                                            "templateRequired": false,
                                            "documentId": 1,
                                            "tabLabel": "Signature_ContractNumber",
                                            "required": true,
                                            "recipientId": "1"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "shared": false,
                                            "requireInitialOnSharedChange": false,
                                            "requireAll": false,
                                            "locked": false,
                                            "concealValueOnDocument": false,
                                            "disableAutoSize": false,
                                            "templateLocked": false,
                                            "templateRequired": false,
                                            "documentId": 1,
                                            "tabLabel": "Signature_ContractNumber",
                                            "required": true,
                                            "recipientId": "1"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "shared": false,
                                            "requireInitialOnSharedChange": false,
                                            "requireAll": false,
                                            "locked": false,
                                            "concealValueOnDocument": false,
                                            "disableAutoSize": false,
                                            "templateLocked": false,
                                            "templateRequired": false,
                                            "documentId": 1,
                                            "tabLabel": "Signature_ContractNumber",
                                            "required": true,
                                            "recipientId": "1"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "shared": false,
                                            "requireInitialOnSharedChange": false,
                                            "requireAll": false,
                                            "locked": false,
                                            "concealValueOnDocument": false,
                                            "disableAutoSize": false,
                                            "templateLocked": false,
                                            "templateRequired": false,
                                            "documentId": 1,
                                            "tabLabel": "Signature_ContractNumber",
                                            "required": true,
                                            "recipientId": "1"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "shared": false,
                                            "requireInitialOnSharedChange": false,
                                            "requireAll": false,
                                            "locked": false,
                                            "concealValueOnDocument": false,
                                            "disableAutoSize": false,
                                            "templateLocked": false,
                                            "templateRequired": false,
                                            "documentId": 1,
                                            "tabLabel": "Signature_ContractNumber",
                                            "required": true,
                                            "recipientId": "1"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "shared": false,
                                            "requireInitialOnSharedChange": false,
                                            "requireAll": false,
                                            "locked": false,
                                            "concealValueOnDocument": false,
                                            "disableAutoSize": false,
                                            "templateLocked": false,
                                            "templateRequired": false,
                                            "documentId": 1,
                                            "tabLabel": "Signature_ContractNumber",
                                            "required": true,
                                            "recipientId": "1"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "shared": false,
                                            "requireInitialOnSharedChange": false,
                                            "requireAll": false,
                                            "locked": false,
                                            "concealValueOnDocument": false,
                                            "disableAutoSize": false,
                                            "templateLocked": false,
                                            "templateRequired": false,
                                            "documentId": 1,
                                            "tabLabel": "Signature_ContractNumber",
                                            "required": true,
                                            "recipientId": "1"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "shared": false,
                                            "requireInitialOnSharedChange": false,
                                            "requireAll": false,
                                            "locked": false,
                                            "concealValueOnDocument": false,
                                            "disableAutoSize": false,
                                            "templateLocked": false,
                                            "templateRequired": false,
                                            "documentId": 1,
                                            "tabLabel": "Signature_ContractNumber",
                                            "required": true,
                                            "recipientId": "1"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "shared": false,
                                            "requireInitialOnSharedChange": false,
                                            "requireAll": false,
                                            "locked": false,
                                            "concealValueOnDocument": false,
                                            "disableAutoSize": false,
                                            "templateLocked": false,
                                            "templateRequired": false,
                                            "documentId": 1,
                                            "tabLabel": "Signature_ContractNumber",
                                            "required": true,
                                            "recipientId": "1"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "dateSignedTabs": [
                                        {
                                            "documentId": 1,
                                            "tabLabel": "Signature_LesseeContract1_eSignDateSigned",
                                            "recipientId": "1"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "documentId": 1,
                                            "tabLabel": "Signature_LesseeSepa1_eSignDateSigned",
                                            "recipientId": "1"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "documentId": 1,
                                            "tabLabel": "Signature_LesseeBillAndCollect1_eSignDateSigned",
                                            "recipientId": "1"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "documentId": 1,
                                            "tabLabel": "Signature_LesseeRequest1_eSignDateSigned",
                                            "recipientId": "1"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "documentId": 1,
                                            "tabLabel": "Signature_LesseeBillAndCollectSepa1_eSignDateSigned",
                                            "recipientId": "1"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                "emailNotification": {
                                    "emailBody": "",
                                    "emailSubject": "Anfrage 2015-06-25T09:10:49: Signieren Sie jetzt Ihren Acme Vertrag",
                                    "supportedLanguage": "de"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "email": "eContractDevelopment@foo.com",
                                "name": "Any Signer",
                                "recipientId": "3",
                                "routingOrder": "3",
                                "tabs": {
                                    "signHereTabs": [
                                        {
                                            "documentId": 1,
                                            "tabLabel": "Signature_SalesFirstBillAndCollect1_eSignSignHere",
                                            "recipientId": "3"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "documentId": 1,
                                            "tabLabel": "Signature_SalesFirstContract1_eSignSignHere",
                                            "recipientId": "3"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "dateSignedTabs": [
                                        {
                                            "documentId": 1,
                                            "tabLabel": "Signature_SalesFirstBillAndCollect1_eSignDateSigned",
                                            "recipientId": "3"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "documentId": 1,
                                            "tabLabel": "Signature_SalesFirstContract1_eSignDateSigned",
                                            "recipientId": "3"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                "emailNotification": {
                                    "emailBody": "",
                                    "emailSubject": "Anfrage 2015-06-25T09:10:49: Signieren Sie jetzt Ihren Acme Vertrag",
                                    "supportedLanguage": "de"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "email": "eContractDevelopment@foo.com",
                                "name": "Any Signer",
                                "recipientId": "4",
                                "routingOrder": "4",
                                "tabs": {
                                    "signHereTabs": [
                                        {
                                            "documentId": 1,
                                            "tabLabel": "Signature_SalesSecondBillAndCollect1_eSignSignHere",
                                            "recipientId": "4"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "documentId": 1,
                                            "tabLabel": "Signature_SalesSecondContract1_eSignSignHere",
                                            "recipientId": "4"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "dateSignedTabs": [
                                        {
                                            "documentId": 1,
                                            "tabLabel": "Signature_SalesSecondBillAndCollect1_eSignDateSigned",
                                            "recipientId": "4"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "documentId": 1,
                                            "tabLabel": "Signature_SalesSecondContract1_eSignDateSigned",
                                            "recipientId": "4"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                "emailNotification": {
                                    "emailBody": "",
                                    "emailSubject": "Anfrage 2015-06-25T09:10:49: Signieren Sie jetzt Ihren Acme Vertrag",
                                    "supportedLanguage": "de"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "email": "mosstest2@foo.com",
                                "name": "A Reseller",
                                "recipientId": "2",
                                "routingOrder": "2",
                                "tabs": {
                                    "signHereTabs": [
                                        {
                                            "documentId": 1,
                                            "tabLabel": "Signature_ResellerContract1_eSignSignHere",
                                            "recipientId": "2"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "fullNameTabs": [
                                        {
                                            "documentId": 1,
                                            "tabLabel": "Signature_ResellerContract1_eSignFullName",
                                            "recipientId": "2"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "documentId": 1,
                                            "tabLabel": "Signature_ResellerBillAndCollect1_eSignFullName",
                                            "recipientId": "2"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "dateSignedTabs": [
                                        {
                                            "documentId": 1,
                                            "tabLabel": "Signature_ResellerContract1_eSignDateSigned",
                                            "recipientId": "2"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "documentId": 1,
                                            "tabLabel": "Signature_ResellerBillAndCollect1_eSignDateSigned",
                                            "recipientId": "2"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                "emailNotification": {
                                    "emailBody": "",
                                    "emailSubject": "Anfrage 2015-06-25T09:10:49: Signieren Sie jetzt Ihren Acme Vertrag",
                                    "supportedLanguage": "de"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "document": {
                "documentId": "1",
                "name": "Application.pdf",
                "transformPdfFields": "true"
            }
        }
    ],
    "customFields": {
        "textCustomFields": [
            {
                "name": "EContractID",
                "value": "ECID-2015-06-25T09:10:49"
            }
        ]
    }
}

--00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: file; filename="Application.pdf"; documentId=1; compositeTemplateId="1"

[file bits go here]

--00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000--


Response:
{
  "envelopeId": "afee6152-23ba-4bcb-a4ad-5b8d8c4dfd7b",
  "uri": "/envelopes/afee6152-23ba-4bcb-a4ad-5b8d8c4dfd7b",
  "statusDateTime": "2015-06-25T18:12:44.0430000Z",
  "status": "sent"
}


POST: https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/1111111/envelopes/afee6152-23ba-4bcb-a4ad-5b8d8c4dfd7b/views/sender.json?api_password=true

Headers:
Accept:application/json
Content-Type:application/json
X-DocuSign-Authentication:<DocuSignCredentials><Username>****</Username><Password>*****</Password><IntegratorKey>****</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>
Host:demo.docusign.net
Content-Length:16
Expect:100-continue

Request Stream:
{"ReturnUrl":""}


Response:
{
  "url": "https://demo.docusign.net/Member/StartInSession.aspx?StartConsole=1&t=17c4b711-7844-4753-bb2a-fc5251a32deb&DocuEnvelope=afee6152-23ba-4bcb-a4ad-5b8d8c4dfd7b&send=1"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two backslashes not just one before the star so instead of `\*` you need

```
\\*
```

Try replacing your JSON with:

```
"tabLabel": "\\*Signature_LesseeContract1_eSignSignHere",
```

This is covered in the "Automatically Populating Tabs" page in the REST API Guide, See the [Dev Center](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center) -> Documentation page for more info.

[link](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Tabs/Automatically%20Populating%20Tabs.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%2520API%2520References%7CSend%2520an%2520Envelope%2520or%2520Create%2520a%2520Draft%2520Envelope%7CTab%2520Parameters%7C_____2)